# How can I disable showing iTunes music purchases in iOS 9?

Tags: itunes, music, ios

I just updated my iPhone 5S to iOS 9. Things work well, but one setting I remember seeing in iOS 8.4 and earlier was the ability to enable/disable showing music purchases in iTunes seems to be gone.

This is quite annoying since I am old fashioned, don’t do streaming and like to have my music offline and directly on my iPhone. So music purchased from iTunes ends up having duplicate track entries. One for the MP3 on my iPhone and another for the iTunes purchased item that's there to let me download it again; see pic below:

[image: La Luz single with duplicate track listings.]

I checked all of the settings and even searched settings for the “Show iTunes Purchases” but all I can find is an option to enable/disable that for video content but not music; see pic below:

[image: "Show iTunes Purchases" for video.]

So what happened to this feature for music in iOS 9?

And FWIW, when I go to “Settings -> Music” the “Show Apple Music” option is deactivated. And I am not using “iTunes Match” so that option is simply shown as “Subscribe to iTunes Match” so there is no “iCloud Music Library” in place to activate/deactivate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So this the ability to enable/disable showing iTunes purchases still exists, but it's not under settings. It’s right in the iTunes app itself.

Launch the app and then click on the pull down which allows you to select iTunes listings like by artist, album and all that; pic below for reference:

[image: iTunes main screen.]

When you click on it look at the bottom of the list. There is a toggle called “Only Offline Music.” Pic below:

[image: iTunes screen showing "Only Offline Music"]

Select that and then… Violà! Listings are back to normal again!

[image: Non doubled up listings in iTunes.]